# How to define a type parameter list?

Tags: generics, f#

given this following type and its member implementation of `apply`

```
type Result<'TSuccess, 'TError> =
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Error of 'TError
    with
    member this.apply (fn:'a) : 'b =
        match (fn, this) with
        | Success(f), Success(x) -> Success(f x)
        | Error(e), Success(_) -> Error(e)
        | Success(_), Error(e) -> Error(e)
        | Error(e1), Error(e2) -> Error(List.concat [e1;e2]);;
```

I get this warning (among others)

```
  member this.apply (fn:'a) : 'b =
         -----------^^^^
  /Users/robkuz/stdin(385,12): warning FS0064: This construct causes code to 
  be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 
  'TError has been constrained to be type ''a list'.
```

And this error

```
type Result<'TSuccess, 'TError> =
-----------------------^^^^^^^
/Users/robkuz/stdin(381,24): error FS0663: This type parameter has been used 
in a way that constrains it to always be ''a list'
```

I tried to change it to

```
type Result<'TSuccess, 'TError list> =
```

and

```
type Result<'TSuccess, List<'TError>> =
```

both giving me a syntax error.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `| Error of 'TError list`?

Comment: How is this supposed to work? It looks as though `fn` should be a `Result<'a -> 'b, 'TError list>`? But you have specified the type as `'a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ildjarn rightly says, you need to change your definition of the `Error` case. Still, this would give you further warnings about `'b`. The best thing really is to strip off all your type annotations, and let F# do the work:

```
    type Result<'TSuccess, 'TError> =
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Error of 'TError list
    with
    member this.apply fn =
        match fn, this with
        | Success f, Success x -> Success (f x)
        | Error e, Success _ -> Error e
        | Success _, Error e -> Error e
        | Error e1, Error e2 -> Error (List.append e1 e2)
```

I think it would help if you wrote a bit more what you are planning to do with this type - the `apply` function has type `Result<('TSuccess->'a),'TError>->Result<'a,'TError>` Should that mean: In the success case, you get a function from one source, a value from another source, and you apply one to the other?

Comment: Trying to implement an applicative via inlining